# Decompression of 2 byte to 4 byte float

Tags: c#, floating-point, compression

I have some animation data (x,y,z), which is represented as 2 byte structures and written in Little Endian. I know that they should be a 4 byte floating point, so i have to unpack them. I collected a few sample values as precise as it was possible (they doesn't represent exactly packed values, but very close to them) and roughly divided packed values on few ranges.

### Sample values (Little Endian):

- 0.048879981    -    0x0046
- 0.056879997    -    0x0047
- 0.253880024    -    0x0050
- 0.313879967    -    0x0051
- 0.623880029    -    0x0055
- 1.003879905    -    0x0058
- -0.066120029    -    0x00С8
- -0.1561199428   -    0x00СD
- -0.8691199871   -    0x00D7

### Ranges:

- 0x0000         : **zero**
- [0x0000,0x0014] : invisible changes (increasing probably)
- [0x0014, ....]  : increasing (visible)
- 0x0080         : **zero**, probably the point of  sign change
- [0x0080,0x00B0] : invisible changes (decreasing probably)
- [0x00B0, ....]  : decreasing (visible)

There are gaps (....) on the ends of ranges because it is hard to check  them correctly, but i assume such big values which are lying close to these ends doesn't used in practice.

Also, it looks like a symmetry between positive and negative ranges, for example i tested **0x0058** which gave  **1.003879905** and **0x00D8** which gave value close to **-1.003879905** but not precise. Maybe it happened because of slightly offset observed after **0x0080**, when visible decreasing starts from **0x00B0**, but it should be about **0x0094** if entire range  had equal symmetry. But slight measure inaccuracy might be as well.

So, how to get a function in C#, that will convert source data to   4 byte floating point?

Comment: Where do you get _“2 byte”_ (16 bit) from?  `uint` is [32 bit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types).  `float/Single` is also 32 bit so not sure why you are packing

Comment: ...your question also sounds like you are seeking _code review_ because there is _no actual problem to solve_. [ask].  Good luck

Comment: I read Uint16 from a file with ReadUInt16(), and I'm strongly believe, that stored values supposed to be a 4 byte floating points when extracted. The actual problem is how to convert these Uint16 (or Int16) to the single-precision floating-point value properly. Maybe my code is wrong and someone can provide any other solutions.

Comment: (a) What information do you have about the 16-bit floating-point format that is being used? (b) What sample values do you have, showing some 16-bit floating-point values and the numbers they represent? (c) How have you “written a piece of code in C#”? It would not be possible to write the code you have shown without having more information than you have given us. The code is clearly an attempt to convert IEEE-754 binary16 or something like it to IEEE-754 binary32. That is not code that comes out of thin air. Where did you get it or the information to write it?

Comment: Use a cast not compression.  A floating point number contains an exponent and you algorithm isn't using the math.power method.

Comment: @jdweng: That will not work to convert a 16-bit floating-point representation not supported by C#. It is necessary to manipulate the bits representing the object.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Thank you for replies, I collected some new information, probably my question will be more clear now

Comment: Are you sure those bit patterns (0x0046, 0x0047,…) are codes for .048879981, .056879997, and so on, and not for 6, 7, 32, 40, 80, 128, −8, −20, and −112?

Comment: How did i get it: in the game i know that default position of the model is some fixed  floating point number that i can change through finding it in memory. Animation can change root position of this model, but not this number in memory (I clearly sure about that and if you want i can explain  more detail). So I wrote 2 byte number in file and then observed new position of the model in the game, after that i returned value in animation to zero and changed position of the model through memory while positions did not match. Then i calculated which value in float gave 2 byte test value.

Comment: for example: [float] unpacked_val =  [float] fixed_default_pos - [uint16] test_data

Comment: I took patterns like 0x0046, 0x0047 only for  convenience, but in practice first byte could be whichever

Answer (score 1):

Some initial comments based on the information in the question so far:

- `byte[] buffer = new byte[4];` is a bad approach because it addresses bytes individually while the other code manipulates bits using shifts within words, and C# does not define endianness. Simply use an unsigned 32-bit integer for all the work. The code will actually be simpler.
- The code does not handle subnormal values properly. If `num2` is zero and `num3` is not zero, the significand (`num3`) must be shifted and the exponent (`num2`) must be adjusted.